# How to use fussion auth for alexa account linking

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to use fusion auth for account linking for alexa vsk. Not finding any resources with this, Please help..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with FusionAuth, but you would want to start by looking at their [OAuth documentation](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/oauth/#configure-application-oauth-settings). Then, in the "Build" section of the Alexa Developer Console, on the left side menu go to Account Linking. Set up the URLs, client ID, client secret, and other settings per FusionAuth's documentation. More information about account linking [here](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/steps-to-implement-account-linking.html). (Please do read the entire Account Linking section in Amazon's Alexa Documentation.)